# «O Coliseu é o ex-libris de Roma.» Como se chegou a este significado de «ex-libris»?

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu

***Ex-libris*** é uma expressão latina que significa segundo a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ex-l%C3%ADbris) ***de entre os livros***. Consultando o [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex%20libris) e o [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ex-libris) (o significado duma expressão latina deve ser o mesmo em qualquer língua) fica-se com um ideia mais clara: ***(proveniente) dos livros (de alguém)***. E de acordo com qualquer dicionário ou a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_libris), um *ex-libris* é uma inscrição ou vinheta no princípio de um livro para indicar a sua procedência. É também este o significado da expressão em espanhol, francês, italiano e inglês. Eu não fazia a mínima ideia! Mas se tivesse pensado um bocadinho no que é que *libris* poderia querer dizer...

Para mim um *ex-libris* correspondia só a algo que parece não ser usado no Brasil e que o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ex-l%C3%ADbris) laconicamente descreve como:

> **2** Aquilo que representa algo ou alguém (ex.: a Torre Eiffel é o ex-líbris de Paris).

A [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ex-l%C3%ADbris) é ainda mais lacónica: diz apenas que é um «símbolo». Na minha eperiência, *ex-libris* não é um símbolo qualquer: designa sempre algo que é do mais espetacular ou famoso que um lugar tem. Este significado de *ex-libris*, *símbolo*, não é partilhado pelo inglês, francês, italiano ou espanhol. E parece que nem sequer pelo português brasileiro: não vem nos dicionários brasileiros, e os raríssimos usos da expressão com este significado que encontro em sites brasileiros [são "não espontâneos", como este](http://www.significados.com.br/ex-libris/).

Então como e quando é que surgiu este segundo significado de *ex-libris*?

Comment: O Aurélio tem: **ex-líbris** [Do lat. *ex libris*, 'dos livros de'.] 1. Fórmula que se inscreve nos livros, acompanhada do nome, das iniciais ou de outro sinal pessoal, para marcar possessão. 2. *Restr.* Pequena estampa, ger. alegórica, que contém ou não divisa, e vem sempre acompanhada do próprio termo _ex libris_ e do nome do possuidor, a qual se cola na contracapa ou em folha preliminar do livro.

Comment: @Earthliŋ A definição do Aurélio corresponde ao que eu descrevo no 1º parágrafo. O outro significado (**2** do Priberam, transcrito na pergunta) parece não existir no Brasil, mas é muito comum em Portugal.

Comment: Eu só coloquei para informação/comprovação que esse outro significado parece não existir no Brasil. Muito curioso...

Comment: @Earthliŋ É curioso, mas não completamente misterioso. *Ex-libris* como indentificador da proveniência de um livro é um termo recente em qualquer língua, finais do século XIX, creio. No outro sentido deve ter sido um desenvolvimento ainda mais recente que só aconteceu em Portugal. estou a editar a pergunta.

Comment: Realmente nunca ouvi esse significado mais genérico aqui no Brasil. Mas faz sentido esse uso, parece um deslizamento do significado original, uma metáfora.

Comment: @bfavaretto, tou a ver a coisa assim: *ex-libris* é *strictu sensu* uma estampa num livro; daí a cartão-postal ilustrado é um pulinho; e daí à coisa ilustrada no cartão-postal é praticamente nada.

Answer (score 2):

Esta [resposta do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ex-libris/2842) explica-o.

Do significado original («nota escrita ou desenhada, aposta no frontispício ou na guarda de um livro, que indica o autor, a livraria ou a pessoa a quem o livro pertence», com [artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookplate)).

Passar daí para coisa que melhor identifica outra coisa é um uso figurado fácil de compreender. Aliás, o mesmo acontece, até com um significado muito semelhante, com *cartão de visita*.

Um exemplo de um uso não literal de *ex libris* pode ser encontrado [nesta passagem de 1917](https://books.google.nl/books?id=PLwwAAAAYAAJ&q=(%22ex%20libris%22%20OR%20%22ex-libris%22)%20AND%20%22sempre%22%20AND%20%22ser%22&dq=(%22ex%20libris%22%20OR%20%22ex-libris%22)%20AND%20%22sempre%22%20AND%20%22ser%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y):

> Canteiros de flores ingénuas (o bem-me-quer serve ao poeta de *ex-libris*).

Algures entretanto a palavra passou a aplicar-se mais (mas não necessariamente) com locais. A distribuição de lemas com mais de uma ocorrência no CETEMPúblico para `("ex-libris" | "ex libris") [lema="de.*"] @[]` é: *cidade* (8), *vila* (4), *capital* (4), *Lisboa* (4), *concelho* (3), *recebedor* (2), *Marinha-Grande* (2), *colecção* (2), *arquitectura* (2), *Tejo* (2), *tradição* (2), *terra* (2), *edifício* (2), *parque* (2), *noite* (2).

Comment: 1880 é o que diz o [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex%20libris). As ocorrências anteriores no Ngram  devem referir-se a outra coisa que não o identificador da procedência dum livro.

Comment: @Jacinto Tens razão.